# Regularizing-a-CNN-with-L2-regularization

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

For CONV2D L2 penalty calculation the code uses p parameter . `l2_penalty = l2_lambda * sum([(p**2).sum() for p in conv_layer.parameters()])`

What is p variable here exactly and iterates for what ? According to my findings , conv_layer.parameters() returns 2 tensor for p. First p in iteration is output tensor .But what is the second p tensor in the iteration ?

The code is as follows :

```py
import torch.nn as nn

loss_func = nn.BCELoss()

loss = loss_func(torch.tensor([0.9]), torch.tensor([1.0]))

l2_lambda = 0.001

conv_layer = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=5,kernel_size=5)

l2_penalty = l2_lambda * sum([(p**2).sum() for p in conv_layer.parameters()])

loss_with_penalty = loss + l2_penalty

linear_layer = nn.Linear(10, 16)

l2_penalty = l2_lambda * sum([(p**2).sum() for p in linear_layer.parameters()])

loss_with_penalty = loss + l2_penalty
```

Comment: Please correct your formatting for future users readability!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the preferred way of regularizing in PyTorch would be to use `weight_decay` parameter in the optimizer, there might be some small differences between weight decay and L2 regularization but you should get a similar effect.

`conv_layer.parameters()` will typically output an iterator over 2 tensor parameters of the conv layer -- weight and bias. You can also run `conv_layer.named_parameters()` to get a `dict` with names and keys, that could help your understanding.